# How to create complex op-amp diagrams with Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circuitikz, circuits, opamp

I am familiar with LaTeX but semi-new to Circuitikz. I am comfortable creating simple diagrams with nodes and bipolar, however combining them with op amps is difficult for me. I am trying to replicate this schematic: [image: what I want]

This is what I have thus far:

[image: what I have]

```
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
\draw
(0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
(opamp.-) to[R,l_=$R_1$,-o] (-2, 0.35) -- (-3, 0.35) to [V=$v_1$] (-3,-0.5) to (-3,-0.5) node[ground]{}
(opamp.-) to[short,*-] ++(0,0.5) coordinate (leftC)
to[R=$R_2$] (leftC -| opamp.out)
to[short,-*] (opamp.out) to [short,-o] (1.5,0) to (1.5,-0.5) node[ground]{}
(opamp.+) -- (-1,-0.35) to (-1,-0.5) node[ground]{}
;\end{circuitikz}
```

The main things I am struggling with which I cannot find resources for are the following:

1. Reducing (a) label size and (b) specific element size such as resistors
2. Adding floating arrows, labels, voltages, and circled numbers
3. Customizing the color of the op amp and labels, and thickness of lines and elements

Thanks in advance for all the help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with code of what you achieved so far, i.e. provide us with an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @marmot Done! :)

Comment: Since circuitikz (TikZ) scales fonts and images separately, it is better to use \scalebox or \resizebox (already loaded) to scale the whole thing together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just for fun an option creating customized components, in the basic way with scope; using circuitikz `support shapes` to declare some points `(N3);(N2);(N6);(N6-OUT),` to draw pasive components, then create a line style using markings to draw reference voltages, because the given by circuitikz looks bad (the minus simbol is shorten than the positive, and the label position is not at the center); for the currents I use the option `midway` to define a node in the middle of the path,and then using the `anchor` and the `inner seperation` to control the text position and finally using a label with style to put the number marks.

RESULT:
[image]
MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}%To allow \cfrac macro
\usepackage{bm}%Bold math
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        %Environment Config
        font=\large,
        MyArrow/.style={%Style for the current
            -Stealth,
            cyan,
            line width=1.5pt,
            shorten >= 5pt,
            shorten <= 1pt
        },
        Vref/.style={%Style for the voltage reference
            draw=none,
            postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.5 with {\node{\Large #1};}}},
            postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.15 with {\node{\Large $\bm{+}$};}}},
            postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.85 with {\node{\Large $\bm{-}$};}}}
        },
        Numbered/.style = {% Style for circle marks
                draw,
                circle,
                line width=1.5pt,
                align=center,
                inner sep=4pt,
                label distance=15pt
           }
    ]
    \def\MyOpamp(#1)#2{%Customized opamp
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
    %Component Shape
    \draw[fill=cyan!25,line width = 2pt, line join=round] (0,0)++(-1,1.5)
        --++(2.5,-1.5) -- ++(-2.5,-1.5)-- cycle; 
    % Label and component identifier.
    \draw(0,0) node{\sf U-#2}; % IC LABEL
    % Draw the pins
    % Some that you have to learn about label nodes, draw lines, and name coordinates in Tikz
    \draw[line width = 1.5pt] (-1,1) node [anchor=180]{$-$} -- ++(-0.5,0)  coordinate (#2 IN-); % IN - 
    \draw[line width = 1.5pt] (-1,-1) node [anchor=180]{$+$}  -- ++(-0.5,0) coordinate (#2 IN+); % IN +
    \draw[line width = 1.5pt] (1.5,0)  -- ++(0.5,0) coordinate (#2 OUT); % OUT  
    \end{scope}
    }
    \def\MyGround(#1)#2{%customized ground
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
    %Component Shape
    \draw[line width = 2pt, line cap=round]
    (0,0) coordinate (#2 GND)++(-0.3,0)--++(0.6,0)
    (0,-0.15)++(-0.2,0)--++(0.4,0)
    (0,-0.3)++(-0.1,0)--++(0.2,0);  
    \end{scope}
    }

    %Put the customzed opamp in position
    \MyOpamp(0,0){1}

    %Put some short nodes
    \draw(-7,1) node[ocirc,scale=2,line width=1.5pt](N3){};
    \draw(-3,1) node[circ,scale=2,line width=1.5pt](N2){};
    \draw(3,0) node[circ,scale=2,line width=1.5pt](N6){};
    \draw(5.5,0) node[ocirc,scale=2,line width=1.5pt](N6-OUT){};
    \MyGround(-7,-3){1}
    \MyGround(1 GND -| N2){2}
    \MyGround(1 GND -| N6-OUT){3}

    %Draw the Wires and pasive components
    \draw[line width=1.5pt]
    (N3)%From node N3
        --++(1,0)
        to [R,l=\Large$R_1$] (N2)
        --(1 IN-)
    (N2)
        --++(0,2) coordinate (N5)
        --++(2.5,0)
        to[R,l=\Large$R_2$]++(3,0)
        -| (N6)
    (1 OUT) 
        -- (N6-OUT)
    (1 IN+)
        -|(2 GND);
    %Voltage references
    \draw[Vref=$v_1$]
    (N3) 
        -- (1 GND);

    \draw[Vref=$0$ V,color=cyan]
    (1 IN-)
        ++(-0.5,0) coordinate (temp) 
        -- (1 IN+ -| temp)
        node[
            midway,
            label={[Numbered,black]180:\bf 1}
        ]{};

    \draw[Vref,color=cyan]
    (N6-OUT) 
        -- (3 GND) 
        node [
            midway,
            anchor=west,
            label={[Numbered,black,label distance=5pt]180:\bf 6}
        ]{$\bm{v_o} = 0-\cfrac{v_1}{R_1}R_2$};

    \draw[MyArrow]
    (N2)++(-1.5,-5) 
        node [
            label={[Numbered,black,label distance=5pt]180:\bf 2}
        ](C1){$\bm{v_1} = 0$ \bf (Virtual ground)}
    (C1.168) %get a point from center to node box at 168 degrees
        to [out=80, in=-150] (N2);

    %Draw currents
    \draw[MyArrow]
    (N3)++(0.3,0.3)
        -- ++(1.5,0)
        node [
            midway,
            inner sep=10pt,
            anchor=-70,
            label={[Numbered,black,label distance=0pt]180:\bf 3}
        ]{$\bm{i_1} = \cfrac{v_1}{R_1}$};

    \draw[MyArrow]
    (N2)++(0.5,0.3)
        -- ++(1.2,0)
        node [
            midway,
            inner sep=10pt,
            anchor=-70,
            label={[Numbered,black,label distance=0pt]12:\bf 4}
        ]{$0$};
    \draw[MyArrow]
    (N5)++(0.3,0.3) %node gap
        -- ++(2,0) % Arrow longitude
        node [
            midway,
            inner sep=10pt,
            anchor=-70,
            label={[Numbered,black,label distance=0pt]180:\bf 5}
        ]{$\bm{i_2} = \bm{i_1} =\cfrac{\bm{v_1}}{R_1}$};
    \draw[cyan]
    (C1 -| 3 GND)
        node [
            inner sep=10pt,
            anchor=west,
        ]{$\bm{v_o} = -\cfrac{R_2}{R_1}v_i$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PSD: This code is derived from [How can i rotate circuitkz figure vertical?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/437493/154390), [555 timer schematic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435123/154390), for label styles [drawing circles and squares with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435818/154390)

Answer (score 6):

I made a few changes to make it look more like the original, and to commit fully to relative coordinates.  Note that `to` centers the components between the end points, so to offset the component you need move the end points.

To add text you use normal TikZ nodes (`circuitikz` **is** a `tikzpicture`).  Since they don't have to be perfectly aligned one has some freedom in placement.  I put the first label relative to coordinate `(L1)`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
%\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
\draw (0, 0) node[op amp] (opamp) {}
      (opamp.-) to[short,-*] ++(-1, 0) coordinate(A)
      (opamp.+) -| ++(-1,-1) node[ground](B){}
      (opamp.out) to[short,*-o] ++(1, 0) coordinate(C)
      (C |- B) node[ground]{} node[ocirc]{}
      (A) to[R,l_=$R_1$,-o] ++(-2, 0) -- ++(-1, 0) coordinate(D) to [V<=$v_1$] (D |- B) node[ground]{}
      (A) |- ++(1,1) coordinate[yshift=1ex] (L1) to[R=$R_2$] ++(2,0) -| (opamp.out) to[short,-o] ++(1,0)
;
\draw[blue,->] (L1 -| A) -> (L1);
\node[blue,above left] (L2) at (L1) {$i_1=i_2=\frac{v_1}{R_1}$};
\node[draw,circle,left] at (L2.west) {5};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 6):

as starting point ...

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
\tikzset{every pin/.append style={pin distance=11mm,
                                  pin edge={<-,shorten <=2pt,semithick,cyan},
                                  align=center, text=cyan}}
\ctikzset{bipoles/length=1cm}
\draw   (0,0)   node[below] {$+$}
                to [short,i=\textcolor{cyan}{$i_1{=}\frac{v_I}{R_1}$},o-]    ++ (1,0)
                to [R=$R_1$,-*] ++ (2.0,0)
                coordinate[pin={[xshift=1em]240:{$v_I=0$}\\ (Virtual ground)}] (aux1)
                to [short,i=\textcolor{cyan}{$i_1{=}0$}]    ++ (1,0)
                node [op amp, anchor=-] (amp) {}
        (aux1)  -- ++ (0,2)
                to [short,i=\textcolor{cyan}{$i_2{=}i_1=\frac{v_I}{R_1}$}]    ++ (1,0)
                to [R=$R_2$]    ++ (2,0)
                |- (amp.out)
                to [short,-o]   ++ (2,0)
                node[below] {$+$}
                to [open,l=\textcolor{cyan}{$v_o{=}0-\frac{v_1}{R_1}$}] ++ (0,-2)
                node[ground,label=$-$] (aux2) {}
        (amp.+) -| (aux1 |- aux2)
                node[ground] {}
        (0,0)   to [open,l_=\textcolor{cyan}{$v_I$}] (0,0 |- aux2)
                node[ground,label=$-$] (aux2) {}
        ;
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```