# How to make this scheme look a bit better?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, circuitikz, decorations

Im working on the next scheme
[image]

What improvements can be added?

Specially the decoration item.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages,scale=2]
   \draw (0,0) node [op amp,scale=1.5](amp){};
   \draw (amp.+) to [short,-*] ++(0,0) node[ground]{};
   \draw (amp.-) to [R=\SI{$R_1$}{\ohm},-o] ++(-2,0) to [V=\SI{1}{V}] ++(0,-2) node[ground]{};
   \draw (amp.out) to [short] ++(1,0) to [R=\SI{$R_l$}{\ohm}] ++(0,-2) node[ground]{};
   \draw (amp.-)  to [short,*-] ++(0,1) to [R=\SI{$R_2$}{\ohm}] ++(2,0)  to [short,-*] ++(0,-1.37);
 \draw  (-2.25,-0.2) node [1] {} 
  node[right,blue] {$i_P=i_N=0\,A$};
\draw [decorate,thick,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,raise=1ex,mirror},color=blue]
                  (-0.85,0.4) -- (-0.85,-0.4) node[midway,yshift=0em,xshift=-4.5em]{{$v_P=v_N=0\,V$}};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you mark in your given image what you want to change? "more professional" is a bit unclear and opinion based ...

Answer (score 6):

More "professional look" is very opinion based. So, a way as I would draw your shem may differ a lot from the way as would draw someone else :-)

```
\documentclass[border=3.131592]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                }
\tikzset{
BC/.style = {blue, decorate,
    decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
    pre =moveto, pre  length=2pt,
    post=moveto, post length=2pt,
    raise=3pt},% for mirroring of brace
    very thick,
    pen colour={blue}},
        }
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[american voltages]
\node   (amp) [op amp,scale=2] {};
\draw   (amp.-) to [R,a=$R_1$,-o]   ++ (-3,0) -- ++ (-1,0) 
                to [V=\qty{1}{V}]   ++ (0,-3)
                node[ground] {} 
        (amp.-) to [short,*-]           ++ (0,2)    coordinate (aux) 
                to [R=$R_2$]  (aux -| amp.out)  
                to [short,-*]       (amp.out) --  ++(1,0) 
                to [R=$R_l$] ++(0,-2) 
                node[ground] {}
        (amp.+) -- ++ (0,-1) node[ground] {};
\draw[BC] (amp.+) -- 
    node[left=3mm, font=\small, align=right] {$i_P=i_N=0\,A$\\
                                              $v_P=v_N=0\,V$} 
                (amp.-);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I correct resistor labels. Now MWE is compilable.

Comment: Indeed, its my opinion and its totally subjective.  But I think its a very good idea to define the style this way.

Comment: @corie Check the following example with modifying styles https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/441787/154390